# How can I use an Eclipse formatter profile in VIm?

Tags: eclipse, vim, editor, code-formatting

My team has a standard Eclipse code formatter profile. I prefer to work with VIm. Is there any way I can convert this file and use it with VIm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably just configure vim to run the formatter automatically when writing your files.

Formatter invocation from the commandline *(google)*:

```
<path-to-eclipse>\eclipse.exe -vm <path-to-vm>\java.exe -application
org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter -verbose -config
<path-to-config-file>\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
<path-to-your-source-files>\*.java
```

**Tip:** with expand("%:p") you can get the full path to your file...

I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, this looks promising. I'm not at work today, but I'll give it a shot tomorrow. Thank you!